# Stop MVC4 emitting script tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a layout template that is xml and has no <script> tag in it. However when the page is generated <script/> has been generated as the first child element of the root element. Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: It shouldn't just put a `<script />` tag in there by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not default behaviour.  Can you check the html of your view and make sure there is no empty script in there?

Comment: Aargh......!!!! I was viewing the page using chrome and it adds the empty script tag in its default style sheet - when I view the source its not there. doh!!

Comment: that could be annoying ;)  you could overwrite their style sheet with a reset and this might get rid of that if it is getting in the way.